# how do i delete file from public folder on my laravel project

Tags: laravel

i have a laravel project and i want to delete image from this directory

`myLaravelProject/public/images/banners`

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete("images/banners/{$image_name}");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: in other words, you dont need those brackets `{ }` around your variable as it will double interpret the variable. Or simply use `'/images/banners/'.$image_name`

Comment: @N69S I don't think that's a relevant dupe, as it'll work just the same (see https://3v4l.org/j5Z2t).

Comment: @arashkenji Have you ensured that `$image_name` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: find the path of your file from public (you can use `public_path()` OR `asset('')`), then do this: `unlink($file_path);`.

Answer (score 0):

For good practice you need to edit config with a new storage disc in `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'public_uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/images/banners/',
]
```

and then

```
 Storage::disk('public_uploads')->delete("{$image_name}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me:

```
use File;

$file_path = public_path(substr($this->path, 1));

if(File::exists($file_path)) {
    File::delete($file_path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 8, this code works for me:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File; 


$file_path = public_path('upload/test.png');

if(File::exists($file_path)) {
    File::delete($file_path);
}
```

I hope it helps!